# Parsing a URL Query inside a URL Query

Tags: php, zend-framework2

At some point in my application the user is sended to this URL:

```
https://mysite.com/bframe/auth?next=/bframe?foo=bar&foo2=bar2
```

As you can see, the *next* parameter in the URL actually contains a new url query, that have *foo* and *foo2* as parameters. To parse the next parameter in Zend2 im using just:

```
$next = $this->getController()->getRequest()->getQuery('next', null);
```

But that gives me back just the first parameter `/bframe?foo=bar` trimming *&foo2=bar2*, that kinda makes sense since *getQuery* sees the first question mark as the query? I dont get it quite well, the thing is, how can I retrieve the complete value of *next*?

Answer (score 1):

`urlencode()` your "next" content

```
$url = 'https://mysite.com/bframe/auth?next=' . urlencode('/bframe?foo=bar&foo2=bar2');
```

Your URL should then look like:

```
https://mysite.com/bframe/auth?next=%2Fbframe%3Ffoo%3Dbar%26foo2%3Dbar2
```

And you will note there are no longer any ambiguous `?` and `&` characters

---

As I'm not sure how you're using `$next` next in your code, the concept is to url encode any data you plan to insert into a further url query string structures

Comment: probably better to just stick with a zend impl (since thats the framework of choice for OP), even if it leads to the same result. https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Escaper/Escaper.php

Comment: enconding the url does not make any difference, the getQuery function from Z2 gives me back the same result with encoding or without

Comment: Then that's unfortunate, because that's what you require to have that URL work in the way that you need. Sorry I'm unable to assist further.